# Xamarin Forms CarouselView Loop Binding Doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

I have a collection bound to my `CarouselView` and I want to make the `Loop` property of the `CarouselView` to be true only when there is more than 1 element in the collection. This should be very easy but I don't know why it isn't working

`<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding FoodCards}" Loop="{Binding IsLooping}">`

and in my `ViewModel` I have a command that's executed when I press a certain button to show only one element and set `IsLooping` to `False`

`IsLooping = FoodCards.Count > 1;`

Can this effect be achieved? Or we cannot change `Loop` during runtime?

EDIT:

The workaround from the answers below works if I don't change the collection dimensions. Right now I have a collection of 3 elements bound to the `CarouselView` and I also have a button with a command bound to it. The code from the command is :

```
void OnChangeLoop(){
            Items.Clear();
            Items.Add("item1");
            Items.Add("item2");
            Loop = !Loop;
        }
```

and in the code behind I have the workaround with the `PropertyChanged`.
And when I press the button I get `java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid target position`

Comment: are you using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: yes, I've tried to bind `IsLooping` to a label and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, you can follow the progress on https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13706

#### Workaround (adapted from the linked issue)

Code-behind

```cs
YourPage()       //Constructor
{
      InitializeComponent();
      BindingContext = new YourViewModel();
      (BindingContext as YourViewModel).PropertyChanged += Vm_PropertyChanged;
}

void Vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(YourViewModel.IsLooping))
    {
        carousel.Loop = ((YourViewModel)BindingContext).IsLooping;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you suggest to me a workaround?

Comment: There is a Workaround in the issue I linked, have you tried it ?

Comment: I'm getting this error `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Invalid target position`

Comment: Where (which line)? are you sure it is related to that code and not something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that its related to that code but I get the same error if I do this. `Loop={Binding IsLooping, Mode=TwoWay}`

Comment: Make sure it's not coming from the IsLooping property try replace the line in the if statement with `carousel.Loop = false` or true and see if it's still happening or no

Comment: `carousel.Loop = false` and the error still occurs

Comment: if you remove that line completely will the error remains or disappears?

Comment: I tested it on another example and it worked. It seems like that error is related to the fact that I have 3 items in my collection and when I press the button I modify the collection content. example code to reproduce my error: `void OnChangeLoop()
        {
            Items.Clear();
            Items.Add("item1");
            Loop = !Loop;
        }`

Comment: Ok so it was not related to this code, right ? have you been able to fix it?

Comment: Not really. I'm still trying to figure it out